# Create Dynamically Nested Objects with loops

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I wanna create a nested object dynamically. I can create it hard coded. Is it possible to do this with a loop ?

```
result = {}
keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

result[keys[0]] = {}
result[keys[0]][keys[1]] = {}
result[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]] = {}
result[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]][keys[3]] = "cool"
```

I want to pass an integer for example if it is "3", this should created an object like:

```
result = {
  "a": {
     "b": {
        "c": "cool"
     }
   }
}
```

If it is 4, :

```
result = {
  "a": {
     "b": {
        "c": {
           "d": "cool"
        }
     }
   }
}
```

So on ...

***edit:***

I am also checking result object, in order to create this nested structure. If there is not any field yet, I simply create the object.

Using this structure to group data.
Any chance to check these dynamically ?

```
if (!result[keys[0]]) 
if (!result[keys[0]][keys[1]]) 
if (!result[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]])
```

Comment: will `keys` contain the correct number of input (what if the input is 5)?

Comment: You could do it using recursion and map the index of the iteration with its alphabetical representation.

Comment: @depperm Getting keys as a param of this function. It might change in the future. This is why ı am looking for dynamic solution. You can basically use keys.length in order to determine.

Comment: what problem you have? do you asking how to use for-loop in javascript?

Comment: @appleapple yes,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`reduceRight()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) for this. It just starts from the inside at the last item in the keys list and works its way out starting with "cool":

```js
let keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
let limit = 3

let result = keys.reduceRight((obj, key) => ({[key]: obj}), "cool")

console.log(result)
```

To limit where the object stops you can iterate over a slice of the keys. For example:

```js
let keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
let start = 0
let stop = 3 // slices are don't inlcude the last item, so this will stop at index 2

let result = keys.slice(start, stop).reduceRight((obj, key) => ({
  [key]: obj
}), "cool")

console.log(result)
```

Comment: OP say's he wants to pass an integer, so maybe your keys could be -> `Array(3).fill().map((f, ix) => String.fromCharCode(97 + ix)).reduceRight(....`  etc

Comment: There's a `reduceRight` function?! Oh well, time to do some refactoring. *"I want to pass an integer for example if it is "3", this should created an object like [object three levels deep]."* Might need to add a `slice` before the `reduce`

Comment: Perfect ! 
Any chance to use that between in range. Like start with index 1 ("b") and ends with index 2 ("c")

Comment: Thanks @Keith, I  missed that part.

Comment: @CanerSezgin see the edit. If you take a slice of the keys from start to stop, you can use `reduceRight` over that.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Amazing,  you’re a great help ! Thank you so much.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I added one more question related to the first one. If you are available please help me out with that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you like to **add** to a given object a new property, you could reduce the keys with the object and take default objects for not given keys. At the end assign the value.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value, limit) {
    var keys = path.slice(0, limit),
        last = keys.pop();

    keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object)[last] = value;
    return object;
}

var result = { foo: 42 },
    keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

setValue(result, keys, 'cool');
console.log(result);

setValue(result, keys, 'cool', 3);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

short and simple using reduce

```js
let object1= {}
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']

keys.reduce((prev,curr,i)=>{
    prev[curr] = {}
    return prev[curr]
}, object1)

log(object1) 
// {
//   a:{
//     b:{
//        c:{}
//     }
//   }
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

simple for-loop solution.

```js
let result = {}
let keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
let depth=3;

let current = result
for(let i=0;i<depth;++i){
  let key = keys[i]
  if(i == depth-1) current[key] = 'cool'
  else current = current[key] = {}

}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd use a reducer, along with some basic tests to help me out:
https://youtu.be/D6zLI8zrfVs

[image]

https://gist.github.com/brianswisher/2ce1ffe3ec08634f78aacd1b7baa31f9